# Recursion to solve basic multiplication

Tags: python, recursion, jython, multiplication

I'm supposed to be writing a function that find the amount of shoes a given number of dogs would need. It can easily be done with multiplication, but we're required to use recursion, so i have

```
def dogShoes(n):
    total = 0
    if n>0:
        shoes =   n + dogShoes(n)
        total = total + 1
        if total == 4:
            return shoes
```

But I now realize that line 4 will go towards infinity and the bottom part that I though would stop it won't even be implemented. Is there a way to say when `total` is `4`, stop and return the answer without `shoes` going towards infinity?

Comment: That is the weirdest way to learn recursion I've ever seen.

Comment: Can you use for loops? If so, do that.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts "but we're required to use recursion"

Comment: Right, sorry about that.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2783342/2800918) to a similar question may help you understand recursion better.

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your function a lot:

```
def dogShoes(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 4 + dogShoes(n-1)
```

Since you have to use recursion instead of just returning `n * 4` you can simply rewrite multiplication as addition (recursively).

*What a weird task...*

Comment: Your code is not working for [this dog](http://tripawds.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/product_pics/20160305w_GripTrex14.jpg).

Comment: @wim savage comment is savage

Comment: @wim Well, back to the drawing board. We need more maths (or more legs)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling your function recursively, but never changing the parameter, thus giving infinite recursion.  Try:

```
>>> def dog_shoes(n):
...   if n > 0:
...     return 4 + dog_shoes(n-1)
...   else:
...     return 0
...
>>> dog_shoes(1)
4
>>> dog_shoes(2)
8
>>> dog_shoes(3)
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Mul(n, x):
    if n==1:
        return x
    else:
        return x+ Mul(n-1,x)
```

Here's a simple multiplication function using Python recursion using two arguments.

```
Mul(3,3)
>>>9
```