# Why is my factorial function returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop, nan, factorial

I wrote a factorial function using recursion and a while-loop but it's return value is NaN whenever it is called. Please I want to know why? and how to fix it?

**Function**

```
function factorial(n) {
    while(n > 0)
        return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Comment: where is the base case to end the recursion?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee the base case was my problem. I've fixed it

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the `return` statement for the base case. The function returns `undefined` when you return without a value, and when you multiply that you get `NaN`.

Also, you're not looping, so you should use `if` rather than `while`.

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    return factorial(n - 1) * n;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

console.log(factorial(10));
```

You can also write it with looping instead of recursion.

```js
function factorial(n) {
  result = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result *= i;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(factorial(10));
```

Comment: Thanks... But can't looping be used?

Comment: Either use looping or recursion, but not both.

Comment: I've added the looping version.

Comment: @Hung-Thai has answered my question

Answer (score 2):

If you track your recursion, you'll see when n reaches 1, which make n-1 = 0 and the factorial(0) is called, your function does not know what to do next and does not return any number (NaN). That NaN multiplies with all other things returning another NaN.

Add an instruction for your function in to handle n = 0:

```
function factorial(n) { 
   if (n == 0) return 1;
   while(n > 0)
      return factorial(n - 1) * n;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add the [base case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783306/base-case-in-a-recursive-method) n === 0 to n === 1 to end the tail recursion.**

```js
console.log(function factorial(n) {

  if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }


  return factorial(n - 1) * n;

}(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also write it in single line:

```
const factorial = (n) => (n > 1) ? factorial(n-1) * n : 1
```